# Using a span inside and anchor to apply different font?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I need to target the @ sign in a link to apply a different font to it. I am trying to use a span tag inside the anchor but for some reason it is not working.

[Here](http://angelaandtom.co.uk/philipphumm.com/index.html#) is the website I am trying to apply this too. (please click on the contact link on the bottom right of the page to see the anchor with the @ symbol I am trying to target)

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/qoqdk6ng/) is a fiddle I have been using to solve this problem, however it works on the fiddle and not on the webpage.

```
<div id="contact-info">
 <a href="mailto:me@me.com">contact<span class="jaap">@</span>me.com</a>
```

Comment: Links are of no value to future SO users as they may not be relevant once the problem has been solved. Please provide the relevant HTML& CSS **in the question**

Comment: For me the font in your fiddle does not work at all.

Comment: It appears that font is not located in your font folder.

Comment: The fonts in the fiddle don't work because of cross origin protection. This could possibly be the problem on the website as well. The general markup and CSS seem to work just fine if you, for example, adjust the color as demonstrated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine! :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #000000;
            }
            a span{
                color: #FF0000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="mailto:foo@emial.com">foo<span id="color">@</span>email.com</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```